# Утечка памяти при использовании DataGrid UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста! При каждом обновлении ItemSource постоянно увеличивается память приложения. Что не так?

```
private async void pRefreshTable()
    {
        pProgressRingStart(false);

        pProductsTable.ItemsSource = null;

        pProductsTable.ItemsSource = await pGlobals.uwpApi.pGetProductsCall(_pageSize * _pagePointer - 1, _pageSize);

        pProgressRingStop();
    }
```

Comment: Это не утечка, Garbage Collector соберет мусор как посчитает нужным. Сборка мусора - ресурсоемкая операция, поэтому она не происходит немедленно, чтобы не подвешивать вам приложение.

Comment: [Сборка мусора](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

Answer (score 1):

Такое бывает когда явно не освобождаете память, это не позиционируется как утечка. Это не значит что память не освободится.

Вызовите явно GC (Garbage Collector)  `System.GC.Collect()` что бы запустить процесс. Ну или почитайте хотя бы про сборку мусора в комментарии к вопросу.

Ещё раз скажу это не утечка памяти.

Comment: 1) `GC.Collect` по факту не высвобождает память, а только запускает процесс сборки. 2) в 99,9% случаев - такой вызов только ухудшит производительность приложения, поэтому ваш совет - вредный, и является bad practice. Когда даете такие советы, предупреждайте автора об возможных негативных последствиях. 3) вы не ответили на вопрос, почему потребление памяти растет. Поэтому дарю вам минус.

Comment: Я что где-то написал про gc неправду или данного метода не существует?